# Why does Haskell not allow pattern matching in comprehensions?

Tags: list, haskell, scope, list-comprehension, monads

I've written the following (trivial) function:

```
h c = [f x | x <- a, f <- b, (a, b) <- c]
```

I'd've expected this to be desugared as:

```
h c = do (a, b) <- c
         f <- b
         x <- a
         return (f x)
```

In turn, desugared (ignoring the `fail` stuff) as:

```
h c = c >>= \(a, b) -> b >>= \f -> a >>= \x -> return (f x)
```

However, GHCi returns the error:

```
<interactive>:24:17: error: Variable not in scope: a :: [a1]
<interactive>:20:27: error:
    Variable not in scope: b :: [t0 -> b1]
```

This seems nonsensical, as `a` and `b` are indeed in scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your bindings are in the wrong order.

```
h c = [f x | (a,b) <- c, f <- b, x <- a]
```